# Why does the KC-46 use an MCAS?

Tags: aircraft-design, flight-controls, mcas, boeing-767, tanker

The [KC-46](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_KC-46_Pegasus) tanker aircraft (the U.S. military's designation for the 767s it uses as tankers, and which every other country calls the KC-767) uses an early version of an MCAS.<sup>1</sup>  This was [ostensibly developed to cope with shifts in the aircraft's weight and center of mass during aerial-refuelling operations](http://www.airforcemag.com/Features/Pages/2019/March%202019/USAF-Reviewing-Training-After-MAX-8-Crashes-KC-46-Uses-Similar-MCAS-System.aspx):

> ...  **The KC-46 uses a similar system because the weight and balance of the tanker shifts as it redistributes and offloads fuel.** The KC-46 has a two-sensor MCAS system, which “compares the two readings,” the Air Force said.

However, even though changes in weight and balance as a result of onloading, transferring, and offloading fuel are common to all tankers, and, yet, the KC-135, KC-10, KC-130, KC-30, *et al*, do just fine without any MCASesque system.

What makes the KC-46 special in this regard?

---

<sup>1</sup>: The KC-46's early-model MCAS was later developed (incompetently) into the MCAS version used on the 737 MAX.

Comment: Just spitballing here - maybe because it is the newest of the tankers, and computer processing power had improved enough to easily implement the controllers needed for improved flight control characteristics?

Comment: The real question is, if they had a previous system that compared two sensors, why would they only use one sensor on the 737MAX?

Comment: One only speculate that it was a cost saving measures. One less probe, less installation cost.